# MySQL select where first three letters are different

Tags: mysql, where-clause, limit

Is it possible to do a select statement where it only returns results where the first three letters of the words that you are selecting are different?
If, for example, `select russian from info where english = 'defense';` produces these results
`обороне,оборонного,оборонное`

Then can i say something like
`select russian from info where english = 'defense' and where first three letters are not 'обо';`

This, for example, would result only in.
`обороне'

An example of what the table looks like is below.

```
id,  english,  russian
1    defense   обороне
2    defense   оборонного
3    defense   оборонное
4    defense   другой
```

I would want one of the results that begins with обо, and I would want другой as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `english` and the first 3 chars of `russian` and return the min value of `russian`:

```
SELECT english, MIN(russian) russian
FROM info
GROUP BY english, LEFT(russian, 3)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a407471a325b5b8ac1b7b29b6de75300).
Results:

| english | russian |
| --- | --- |
| defense | обороне |
| defense | другой |

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
select russian from table where english = 'defense' and english not like 'обо%';
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I want to get one of the обо results and it looks like that this query would return none of them.